# Windows Phone 8 optimized insertion into sqlite table from json array

Tags: c#, json, sqlite, windows-phone-8

My Windows Phone 8 app is downloading a list of items from a server in json format:

```
{
  "error":false,
  "lists":[{
    "code":1,
    "name":"item 1"
  },{
    "code":2,
    "name":"item 2"
  },{ 
  ... 
  },{
    "code":100000,
    "name":"item 100000"
  }]
}
```

As should be noticed, my app is downloading 100.000 items.

Then my app decodes the json and iterates each item in order to insert it into the mobile app SQLite database:

```
JObject content = JObject.Parse(result);
string jsonLists = content.GetValue("lists").ToString().Trim();
JArray jarrTAR = JArray.Parse(jsonLists);

foreach (JObject content2 in jarrTAR.Children<JObject>())
{
    string code = content2.GetValue("code").ToString().Trim();
    string name = content2.GetValue("name").ToString().Trim();
    ...
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(MainPage.DBPath))
    {
        db.RunInTransaction(() =>
        {
            db.Insert(new Table1()
            {
                Code = code,
                Name = name,
                ...
            });
        });
     }
}
```

This works, but it takes more than 10 minutes inserting the 100.000 items into the database.

I think this approach (insert items one by one into the table) may be acceptable for a few items downloading, but what should be the recommended strategy for inserting the items when the amount of them are about 100.000?

Is there any way for inserting the total items in one query in order to optimize the insertion time?

Comment: Why are you not using RunInTransactionAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time is probably spent opening/closing database connection since you are creating new connection for each item and then "running in transaction" one item at a time.

You should first create e.g. a `List` of objects you want to insert and then insert all items in transaction. Say...

```
db.RunInTransaction(() => db.InsertAll(items));
```

You could also use `async/await` and run this operation as a new `Task`.

```
private async void SomeMethodHere()
{
    ...

    var myItems = new List<Table1>();
    foreach (JObject content2 in jarrTAR.Children<JObject>())
    {
        // create and/or populate collection here
    }

    await InsertAsync("my.sqlite.path", myItems);
}

public Task InsertAsync(string dbPath, IEnumerable<Table1> items)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
                connection.RunInTransaction(() => connection.InsertAll(items));
        });
}
```

Comment: Or if you'd use `SQLite-net`s `SQLiteAsyncConnection` then you could replace above methods with their *Async counterparts and drop `Task.Run` entirely.

Comment: now I am downloading and inserting 7000 items in only 20 seconds. I have used: db.RunInTransaction(() => db.InsertAll(items)); thanks a lot.